# Debug Timeout Issue - Firefox Dev Edition & Aptana 3

Tags: macos, debugging, firefox, aptana3

OS:         MAC OSX 10.10.1
Aptana:     3.6.1
Browser:    Firefox Developer Edition 36.0a2 w/(Firebug 3.0.0 Alpha 6)

Hi All,

I'm trying to do a simple debug session and this is what happens.
Firefox:  http://www.aptana.com/?debugger=true&port=50627
Aptana:   Launching Firefox - Internal Server encountered a problem.    Socket connection error. Please try shutting down and restarting your web browser, and then run 'debug' again.
Accept timed out

In Aptana Preferences> General >Web Browser I added Firefox and set it to default.  And the location is correct.  No parameters.

Any ideas or help would be awesome.

- Flex